# Как задать время для onmouseout

Tags: css

Прописал для ссылки `onmouseover="body.style.background='#400000';` и обратно `onmouseout = "body.style.background='';"`
для смены цвета `body`, хотелось бы смену производить плавно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот в css

```
body {
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
html:hover body {
    background-color: #400000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/65CDS/

Comment: фига, браузеры теперь и так могут

Comment: eicto, Спасибо большое за помощь! Очень помог. А вот еще такой вопросик, можно ли еще задать к этому коду прозрачность? Слишком уж перекрывает содержимое сайта. Попробовал прописывать, не получается ни как.

Comment: @DimasikYES, Задавайте новые вопросы новой темой.